# Migrating content (posts) from a sister site. Would it be beneficial adding them as pages or post?

Tags: seo, wordpress, optimization

I have to migrate the content (about 150 posts) from a sister website (that client had raised in order to increase SEO on advice from an SEO company) to the main website.

My client has got a conception that migrating these posts as pages would benefit the health of their website more than having them as posts.

In my opinion having them as posts would make more sense plus would make it easier for me to manage the structure/hierarchy of the website but I would like someone else's opinion that sounds much better.

Comment: What is the difference between a page and post?  Are we talking about a forum here with multiple posts per page?  Or is this a blog where each post typically gets its own page?

Comment: The question was tagged with "WordPress" - see: [WordPress.com - Post vs. Page](http://en.support.wordpress.com/post-vs-page/). By default, posts are "listed in reverse chronological order" on the home or posts page. Since the OP is discussing "migrating these posts as pages", and having to restructure them if so, it seems apparent they're currently not static pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the posts on the other site are already indexed in search engines, you might just consider linking back to your main site, or doing 301 redirects to it. If you duplicate the posts on your main site, you're going to have [duplicate content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en) issues, which can be managed through [Canonicalization](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en).

In regards to pages versus posts, posts are better organized as posts since they're generally timely (and marked & organized as such), versus static pages, and search engines tend to like organized content. If it's easier for you to manage and structure them as posts, then it's likely easier for visitors and search engines to understand them that way too.

In short, you might benefit from links coming from the other site (providing that it doesn't have any penalties), versus trying to add and structure the posts on your main site just in the attempt to increase SEO that way.